# convert vector<unique_ptr<T>> to vector<unique_ptr<const T>>

Tags: c++, c++11

How to convert `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` to `vector<unique_ptr<const T>>`?

Any downside of using `reinterpret_cast`? What's recommended way to do so in C++11 and forward?

```
vector<unique_ptr<const T>> Get() {
  vector<unique_ptr<T>> some;
  ...
  // Any better way to do this?
  return *(reinterpret_cast<vector<unique_ptr<const T>>*>(&some));
}
```

Comment: Does it work to just do `return { some.begin(), some.end() }` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: unique pointers aren't copyable.

Comment: @Kerrek: Ahh right. you'd need a move-iterator adaptor.  Still, moving all the existing `unique_ptr<T>` into `unique_ptr<const T>` in the new vector is the right approach, since `reinterpret_cast` is UB.

Comment: If you cross your fingers and go down the `reinterpret_cast` path, make sure you only use references to this `vector<unique_ptr<const T>>`. In your snippet, the returned value from `Get()` will `delete` all of your `T`s when it dies, causing a double deletion later on.

Answer (score 5):

You can construct a new vector by moving the contents of the old vector into it:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> v; // ...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const T>> cv(
    std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```

Your proposed `reinterpret_cast` results in undefined behaviour.

The general theme of your question is that you are trying to *view* a resource-managing handler for one thing as though it was for another, related thing. This is a problematic notion, since the handler really needs to know what exactly it is handling, and it is missing the point somewhat. What you really want to do is communicate a view on the *handled* thing. In the current context, you might take the handled thing, a `T` pointer, and convert *that* to a `const T` pointer using the usual language rules, which works as expected and avoids talking about the handler object (the unique pointer).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't want to transfer ownership, you can create a vector of observer pointers:

```
template<class T>
using const_observer_ptr = const T*;

template<class T>
auto Get() {
    std::vector<const_observer_ptr<T>> some;

    some.resize(source.size());
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), some.begin(),
                   [](auto&& unique) { return unique.get(); });
    return some;
}
```

If you want to move the objects, then see the other answers.